# Push selected option on click

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Im using Node.js, but i really don't know how i can do this guys, pls help

i need push selected option when user click on button, like a cart.

to before submit

```
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [codigo, setCodigo] = useState('');
  const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
  const [descricao, setDescricao] = useState('');
  const [preco, setPreco] = useState('');
  const [peso, setPeso] = useState('');
  const [itemServico, setItemServico] = useState('');

  const [servicos, setServicos] =useState([ ]);


  useEffect(() =>{

    async function loadServicos(){
      const response = await api.get("/api/servicos");
      console.log(response.data);
      setServicos(response.data);

    }
    loadServicos();

  },[])
```

how can i do this,

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                  <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label"></InputLabel>
                    <Select
                      
                      native
                      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                      id="selectServico"
                    >
                      {servicos.map((opcao) => ( 
                        <option aria-label="None" value={opcao._id}>{opcao.codigo_servico}" - "{opcao.nome_servico}</option>
                      ))}
                    </Select>
                    <Button onClick={itemServico.push(document.getElementById("selectServico"))}>Adicionar</Button>
                  </FormControl>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. Please note that I couldn't througly test this as I don't have the full context of your app.

```
export default function App() {
  const [servicos, setServicos] =useState([]);
  const [itemServico, setItemServico] = useState([]);
  const select = useEffect();

  const add = () => {
    if(!itemServico.includes(select.current.value))
      setItemServico([...itemServico, select.current.value])
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select               
      native
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="selectServico"
      ref={select}
    >
      {servicos.map((opcao) => ( 
        <option aria-label="None" value={opcao._id}>{opcao.codigo_servico}" - "{opcao.nome_servico}</option>
      ))}
    </Select>

      <Button onClick={add}>Adicionar</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We create a reference to the Select element by using the `useRef` hook. This will allow us to access the Select's value at any time.

We also create a function, `add`, that adds the selected option's value to the `itemServico` array. But it only does so if the value being added does not already exists in the array.

Finally, we use the `onClick` prop of the button to call the `add` function. This, in a nutshell, is what you would need.